# ImageView setScaleType not working

Tags: java, android

I have an ImageView and I want to to scale `CENTER_CROP`. If I set the image src and scale type in XML it works great. But I need to set the image in code. The following fails to scale correctly. Instead of center cropping it stretches the image to fill the width.

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_image);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

I tried reordering these lines and I tried leaving out the `setScaleType` and leaving that to the XML. Neither helps.

Comment: use setImageResource instead

Comment: @yahya Oops, silly mistake. Thanks. If you put that as the answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`setBackgroundResource` sets imageView's background so it is normal behaviour that stretches...

Use `setImageResource` instead, it will set imageview's source so it will follow your scaleType definition.

Answer (score 0):

and not forget that your ImageView must be NOT:

```
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

but ONLY:

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

for proper transformation