# Changing the imageview image without scaling or re-sizing through code Android

Tags: android, android-imageview

```
Xml Code <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/zod8" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/zod12" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The above xml Shows the images as it is without re-size or scaling this is what i wanted. but when i change the image resource through code  `img_view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.zod10);`it changes the quality and re-sizes the image automatically. how can i fix it thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751008/imageview-setscaletype-not-working), you should instead set via `setImageResource` to avoid this. To be doubly sure you're not scaling anything, you can also set the `ImageView.ScaleType` in your XML to `Center`. This will ensure nothing is scaled, and it will be respected as the scale type when you re-set via `setImageResource`.